PC only boots after reconnecting AC Cable
It's been a few days since I had the problem, that my PC only boots when I unplug my AC cable on the PSU and plug it back in. Only then, the power button would work.
When I try to start it without reconnecting, all lights and fans would turn on for about 0.5 seconds. Then afterwards nothing would happen, even when pressing the power button again.
I already exchanged the PSU with one from work, but same result.
Also, I tried to boot with no/other GPU and other RAM.
Windows Event Viewer says something about losing kernel-power every few days, but not every time I try to start the system:

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

This is the hardware I'm running:

OS: Windows 11 Pro 23H2 x64
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700G
GPU: MSI RTX 3060 Gaming X LHR
RAM: 2x G.Skill 8GB 2133 MHz, 2x G.Skill 8GB 3200 MHz
MB: ASUS Prime B550M-A
PSU: Mars Gaming MPIII850/Enermax Revolution D.F.X 1050


Sudden loss of power (e.g., brief AC line glitch) can damage file systems, making the machine hard to boo, or unbootable. Check the disk, use SFC and DISM to reapir damage, and reinstall Windows 11, keeping files, if the first two attempted fixes fail.  If power glitches are an issue at your locale, use a UPS.

What if you plug in your PC to some other wall outlet? When you disconnect the mains cable, remove the CMOS battery from mobo and long press Power On button on the cabinet for 40 - 45 seconds to clear any static and check again.

@patkim I did try other outlets, even with a whole other circuit at work. Neither this nor the part with the CMOS battery did work.

@DrMoishePippik I ran both commands, the SFC found some results and repaired it, but the Problem is still there.

Have you tried a diferent outlet? Do you live in a region with unstable power?  Do you have an UPS? Your system is indicating it's losing power, likely automatically turning back on, suspect you have the system configured to automatically log back into a profile which is the reason you don't notice the power change.

@Ramhound Like I already said above, I did change outlets and even tried the UPS powered outlets at work, same result

@DNA_Maximal - Only reason I ask is because It's not in the question.

PSU & Mobo are interconnected and handshake. When you shut down the OS the PSU enters StandBy mode whereby it continues to supply around 5V to certain circuits on mobo. However when you unplug it from mains, PSU is then totally Off. If basic troubleshooting did not help, it might point to a HW issue. A local repair shop might be able to diagnose it for you for some small service fee, just in case you do not have a compatible spare mobo etc. Is the Motherboard under Warranty?

Firstly, try to boot your PC using some bootable usb-stick with Linux. If one boots your PC fine, then the problem is on Windows installed.

@patkim Thank you. So it is likely a Motherboard issue? Sadly, there is no more Warranty on any parts of the PC. Do you think, there are further troubleshooting steps I can take, before giving it to a repair shop? Unfortunately, I have no AM4 board lying around, so I can't switch it out.

Make sure that the behavior is same when you have unplugged most components from your PC. Just play around with 1 RAM, GPU, CPU, KB/Mouse. No storage or other peripheral devices at all. I am making a calculated guess that it could be Mobo. The issue could be anywhere. Right from dirty Power to a faulty GPU or failed storage or the way OS shuts down PC. While you play with min components, use a Windows Live Disc like Hiren Boot DVD or a Live Linux to boot to Live OS (Without any storage) and check shutdown.

@JorgeLuiz Sadly this does not work either. Looks like it is really a hardware problem. :(

@patkim I did try that tool. Unfortunately, with the same result, as before.

try to replace the CMOS battery, then try to replace your power supply it can be the issue, also test it if it out of warranty; there is a psu tester and multi-meter
